# Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.): /callback/

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to get a post request from a third-party that deals with payments and I want to get payment transactions from their site through and endpoint called callback. I want to save the transactions in my database but I am getting the following error.Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.): /callback/

I have enabled the CSRF_ALLOWED_ORIGIN and also used the csrf_exempt decorator in the view that will handle post request from the callback but I am getting the error. How do I go about this issue?

Comment: As the error says, you're not sending the correct referer header. You're not sending a referer header at all or you're sending an empty one.

Comment: The request is from a third party and there's no way I can modify it.

Comment: The third party is failing your request because you don't send the referer.

Comment: Is there a way I can send the referer? I am using Nginx as a reverse proxy for my application.